# How to achieve emboss and blur effects on UIBezierpath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Am now creating an application with free hand drawing feature. I would like to add emboss and/or blur effect. Currently I'm using `UIBezierPath`'s `strokeWithBlendMode` for drawing the line.

Please suggest me a way to add these effects.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make such effect would be creating a emboss image and use it with `UIColorWithPatternedImage` for your UIBezierPath's Store Color.

The same applies for blur effect.

Finding an image so that it creates emboss like look is a UI challenge however.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh,           But If i change the stroke color the image pattern too needs to change its color. is it possible in this method?

Comment: I meant, Your color is created from an image so that itself creates emboss or blur effect. It is similar to making effect as if drawing using a chalk. Many app does that.